# if I hide a panel using jQuery how can the settings be restored?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden `div` which I show using jQuery `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`. My hidden `div` has a form which I use and when the field is empty I set the focus using CSS, like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
  var name = $('.name').val();
  if(name == '') {
    $('.name').focus().css({'border':'1px solid #f00'});
  }
  // here goes ajax code
  return false;
});
```

The form which I show is set this way:

```
$('.show_hidden_form').click(function(){
  $('#form_div').slideDown('slow');
});
```

The form is hidden this way:

```
$('.hide_hidden_form').click(function(){
  $('#form_div').slideUp('slow');
});
```

But my issue occurs when I hide the `div` (which it contains the form). I want it to reset the default form style.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Sorry if I'm miss reading you but are you wanting to remove the 1px border from the class name once the div has gone away?

If so, you could add $('.name').css({'border':'0'}); after the slideUp('slow');

If this is what you are asking I can explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a callback function to slideUp:

```
$('.hide_hidden_form').click(function(){
   $('#form_div').slideUp('slow', function() {
       $('.name').focus().css({'border':'0'});   
   }); 
});
```

(By the way, you really should be using an ID for that "name" field instead of a class, since apparently you only have one of them.)

Comment: Great advice, it´s an id, not a class, it´s a typo, thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

You can make a class that contains the default styles of this form and another one (or more classes) to describe other states (i.e. NOT DEFAULTS) and then use

```
 $('#myForm').addClass('submitted')
```

and

```
 $('#myForm').removeClass('defualt')
```

:)

Comment: I thinkk this is the best solution, adding classes to the css file and call them or remove them whenever needed. JQuery should include a resetDefault or something to this kind of situations, Thanks Ahmad, you got the answer I was guessing it should be the solution

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle classes instead. Toggling class is recommended because it is faster, easier to maintain and separates your styling from your code.

```
 //add to your css file
 border { border: 1px solid #f00; }

 //when focus show the border
 $('.name').focus().addClass('border');

 //when unfocus remove the border
 $('.hide_hidden_form').click(function(){
   $('#form_div').slideUp('slow');
   $('.name').removeClass('border');
 });
```